# First four nonzero terms of the McLaurin expansion of $\frac{xe^x}{\sin x}$ at $x_0=0$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Define if necessary the given function so as to be continuous at $x_0=0$ and find the first four nonzero terms of its MacLaurin series.
>   $$ \frac{xe^x}{\sin x}$$

Given $f(x)= \frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$ where $h(x)= xe^x$, and $g(x)=\sin x$

We have the following MacLaurin series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = a_0 + a_1 x +a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 +a_4 x^4 + ...$$
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n = 0 + x+ 0 -\frac{1}{6} x^3 + 0 + \frac{1}{120} x^5 +...$$
$$h(x) = xe^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n =   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n)!}x^n = 0 + x + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} x^3 + \frac{1}{6} x^4  + \frac{1}{24} x^5$$
.

The Maclaurin coefficients of $f(x)g(x)$
$$ c_0 = a_0b_0 = 0$$
$$ c_1 = a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 = a_0$$
$$ c_2 = a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 +a_2b_0 = a_1 $$
$$ c_3 = a_0b_3 +\cdots a_3b_0 = - \frac{1}{6} a_0 + a_2$$
$$ c_4 = a_0b_4 +\cdots + a_4b_0 = - \frac{1}{6} a_1 + a_3 $$
$$ \implies f(x)g(x) = a_0 x^1 + a_1 x^2 + \left( - \frac{1}{6} a_0 + a_2\right)x^3 + \left(- \frac{1}{6} a_1 + a_3\right) x^4 + \cdots$$

.

Equating coefficients of $f(x)g(x)$ with coefficients of $h(x)$
$$ c_0 = 0$$
$$ c_1 =  a_0  = 1 $$
$$ c_2  = a_1 = 1 $$
$$ c_3  = - \frac{1}{6} a_0 + a_2 = 1/2 \implies a_2 = 2/3 $$
$$ c_4  = - \frac{1}{6} a_1 + a_3 = 1/6 \implies a_3 = 1/3 $$
.

it follows that the first 4 nonzero terms are:
$$f(x) = \frac{x e^x}{\sin(x)} = 1 + x + \frac{2}{3} x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^3$$

.

I would like to know if I am  going in the right direction?

My main question regards the original question "*Define if necessary the given function so as to be continuous at $x_0=0$*" . I am not sure how to handle this question, if a definition is needed how? and why? if a definition is not needed how? and why?

Thx for your input/help.

Comment: The definition $$f(0)=1$$ is definitely needed.

Comment: Because $\lim_{x\to 0} \, \dfrac{x}{\sin (x)}=1$ you need to define $f(0)=1$ to have continuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check the computations but, yes, you are doing it right.

As for the other question, note that the expression $\frac{xe^x}{\sin x}$ is undefined if $x=0$. In order to make $f$ continuous at $0$; you must define $f(0)$ as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xe^x}{\sin x}$, which is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your expansion is partially incorrect. After setting $f(0)=1$, note that for $x\not=0$,
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{x e^x}{\sin(x)}&=x \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^4)\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)
\cdot\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\\
&=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)\right)\\
&=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}
+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=1+x+\frac{2x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that
$$(1-z)^{-1}=1+z+z^2+o(z^2).$$